# REGEX for Google Analytics Filters

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have a link with a lot of parameters and want to exclude most of them (only keep one) and replace it for a name

The link has the structure below:
https://www.abc.ab/something/somethingelse?card_type=status&a-bunch-of-trailing

Card_type can have different "status" values

Ideally I would like to keep:
https://www.abc.ab/something/somethingelse?card_type=status and replace ?card_type=status by "/card_type"

I attempted this on GA:

Search string

```
/*(.*?)\card_type\=*
```

Replace string:
/card_type

But this isn't working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `?card_type=` followed by matching any char 0+ times `.*` If it should be from the start of the string you could use an anchor `^` at the start of the pattern.

In the replacement use the first capturing group followed by the replacement string.

```
(.*?)\?card_type=.*
```

- `(.*?)` Capture group 1 matching any char 0+ times non greedy
- `\?` Match a `?` by escaping it
- `card_type=` Match literally
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times non greedy

Replace with

```
$1/card_type
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gLQ0i/1)

To get a bit more precise match for the url instead of using `.*?`, you might match the protocol:

```
^(https?:\/\/\S+\/[^?]*)\?card_type=.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gLQ0i/2)